# Zabbix Active Agents not working over the Internet

Tags: windows, zabbix, zabbix-agent

I have set up my Zabbix server to listen for the active agent which, after messing with my firewall and host names I got to appear green under the monitored status. I also configured the Agent on a Server which is across an Internet connection. I configured the Agent
to become active and send data to my Zabbix Server on a static IP address.

My problem is that i cannot seem to get the data to appear even when cloning and changing a template from "windows agent" to "windows agent active" and I do not fully understand how the client (as in the Zabbix active agent, sending data to the server) will know what the template is asking for if I cannot send data from the Zabbix server to the client over the Internet due to firewall restrictions. The documentation about Active Agents on the Zabbix site is very limited and didn't help me much.

Does anyone have Zabbix active agents working properly across a WAN? If so, can you give me any pointers as to what might be going wrong and where to start trying to resolve the issue?

Unfortunately, it's not viable to run a Zabbix Proxy on the client side or use VPN connections, so the only option is to use active agents.

Comment: Have you tried to telnet from the agent to the Zabbix server port? This will help confirm if the path is actually open and not filtered.